# What is the difference between $.cache and $.data?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery:

What is the difference between `$.cache` and  `$.data`?

Don't both of them provide the same functionality?

Comment: Probably they does but you you have more options in `$.cache` plugin

Comment: I don't think `cache` is part of jQuery. Are you using a plugin? Could you post a link to documentation?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: can you giev me link to official documentation of $.cache? hmm?

Comment: :) , I know , ive just heard they saving it in the $.cache. so i guess its just an internal object inside jQuery . so the public property for it is $.data()----- am i right ?

Comment: `$.cache` is not documented because it's an internal property. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.cache`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L7) is the *internal* hash (`Object`) for caching purposes, [`$.data`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L30) is a function, which provides the [functionality](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and modifies the `$.cache` Object itself.

I would not use `$.cache` at all.